# How to stop images moving when zooming in and out

Tags: html, css, image, sticky

I'm completely new to CSS, HTML and this forum in general. I'm absolutely stumped on how to proceed with the current code I have and I think it overall needs improvemenent (so any help on any of the sections are appreciated). I've looked everywhere for solutions but I'm still a bit confused as all the terms and words are overwhelming.

When zooming in and out on my [webpage](https://phonecharm.neocities.org/), the images move with it instead of "sticking" to where I want it to be.
[Here it is zoomed at 100%, which is what i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox1JF.jpg)  and here it is
[when zoomed in at 150+%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3lsq.jpg)

Here's the entirety of my code I'm sorry it looks like a mess

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.welcome {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 55%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px ridge #BDBDBD;
  padding: 6px;
 background-color: #FFFFEB;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
.heartribbon {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 69%
}
.clover {
 position: absolute;
 top: 78px;
 right: 54.5%
}
body {
  background-image: url("https://suiteypie.neocities.org/bg.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-family:ms gothic
}
.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 94px;
  right: 55%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px ridge #BDBDBD;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: #FFFFEB;
  z-index: -1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<p class="welcome" "absolute"><b><font size="16px"><font color="#F2C1D4"><marquee>WELCOME TO PHONECHARM</marquee></font></font></b></p>
<p class="heartribbon"><img src="https://suiteypie.neocities.org/tumblr_97f9e946bd958c09e8f1a200ddfc6159_0fd770e9_2048.gif"></p>
<p class="clover"><img src="https://phonecharm.neocities.org/tumblr_aa9499dfd31b68905ae3f4e0c39cff25_e354b7fb_1280.gif"></p>
<p class="box1">this page is a current work in progress, do come back soon!</p>
```

I've tried to change the position: absolute to position: relative but then the image disappears.

Comment: Because you set the height/width to pixel(```px```), so when zooming in/out it's will not stay to it's place. Have you try setting up the height/width to ```%```, ```vh``` or ```vw```? *ex:* ( height: 7vh; width: 25vw;)

Comment: @Newbee I changed the `top` and `right` to `vh`, `%` and `vw` however either moved down the page or went to the top left corner, and still moved when i zoomed in and out

Comment: Maybe the design of your page is giving you a trouble so you can't zoom in/zoom out with your desired layout. I suggest you need to clean your codes for the design to easier make an layout.